dotnet external library dependency, dll missing, try-catch block doesn't catch exception
I have a dotnet C# program I wrote that uses an external dll library. When I deploy on production machine, if the external dll is missing or the dll requires a different version of dotnet framework, despite the fact that the line of my code that uses a class from the external library is wrapped in try catch (general catch all block), a runtime exception is thrown without being caught in the catch block.
Interestingly the code is executed up to the line of in my code that uses the class from the external library.
Why wouldn't it be caught in the "catch-all" ?
How can I detect this case in my code if exception is caught?  I'm compiling to framework 4.7.1 (not dotnet core).
Some background:
I am writing a background-service for windows with no GUI and the program communicates out only by logging to the event logger with periodical execution of code, using "Timer" and it is critical for me to get into the catch block so I can log this error and report to the user. The dll I am referencing to is "TpsParser.dll" but this is not important because it can happen with any dll. The exact exception is:

I see many questions on StackOverflow about try-catch doesn't catch exception but my question is particularly about this error of either missing or incompatible external dll.

This exception behaves differently in the Debug build vs the Release build.  In general you can't predict exactly when it is raised, the optimizer that's active in a release build will look ahead in the code for opportunities to inline methods.  So the exception is raised earlier.  Just make it explicit, use Assembly.Load() to get the exception where you want it.


the code is executed up to the line of in my code

This doesn't make sense. When a method is first called, JIT needs to load the external assemblies involved to generate assembly code, and the exception is thrown at this moment, so your try-catch in the Main method didn't even run. So to catch this kind of exception, you need to put the external method calls into another method:
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        AnotherMethod();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
    }
}

[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] 
static void AnotherMethod()
{
    ExternalType.ExternalMethod();
}

